# How delete file& folders on AIX based on the modification timestamp?

Tags: shell, timestamp, aix

I have to ask for help from you with a script runs on AIX. I want to delete files & folders with some name rules on the specified path.

For example, under path `/usr/upself/test`, I have 3 files with name:

```
abc.txt  (modified 8 days ago)
abd.txt  (modified 2 days ago)
abcd.txt (modified 2 days ago)
```

and also have 2 folders with name:

```
abcx     (modified 9 days ago)
abc      (modified 2 days ago)
```

when the script run, it will delete the files and folders with name contains `abc` which is modified 7 days ago.

I used to have a script run on Linux as below, and it is working well:

```js
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
filepath="/usr/upself/test"
cd $filepath

for file in `ls | grep -i abc`
do
 mtime=`stat -c %Y "$filepath$file"`
 curtime=`date +%s`
 gap=$curtime-$mtime

 if [ $[$gap] -gt 604800 ]
 then
  if [ -d $file ]
  then
      rm -r "$file"
  fi
  if [ -f $file ]
  then
      rm -r "$file"
  fi
 fi
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

But unfortunatly, I need to run it on AIX, then we have a problem that on AIX, we don't have command `stat`, and it is stopping the script to get the modification timestamp of the files and folders.

Can anyone help to point out how I need to change the script to make it work as before?

Comment: Do you have a modern, POSIX-compliant `find` on AIX?

Comment: How about `find . -mtime +7`

Comment: @Lorinczy that will find files in subfolders too. And `-mtime +7` means *modified at least 8 days ago*.

Comment: can anyone help to give a hand? on AIX, I tried istat intead of stat command, but can't format the timestamp like just millisecond...

Comment: Find command can find the files, but can't find folders, if the folder with name as 'abc', then can it be found?

Comment: Yes folder 'abc' can be found by find(1) too. It has many options like `-type f` meaning _regular files only_ and `-type d` meaning _directories only._ https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/find.htm

Comment: istat is the alternative for stat command in AIX.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/istat.htm

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond, really thanks for your comment, it is helpful for my question, and it is working!!